# How to execute Fluent Migrator script conditionally in c#

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

My application use desktop application and window service code written in c#.
and Business Logic and Database layer same for both. I am use the Fluent Migrator for CRUD operation in database. 
I want to add some table from desktop application and some from window service.
Can any one know how I bifurcate this from same File. i.e migration file name 
 "M01_Createtble_table1" code below:

```
[Tags("service")]
    [Tags("config")]
    [SchemaMigration("1.1.12")]
    public class M01_Createtble_table1: ForwardOnlyMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            string schemaName = "abc";
            string tableName = "table1";

            if (!Schema.Schema(schemaName).Table(tableName).Exists())
            {
                Create.Table(tableName).InSchema(schemaName)
                      .WithColumn("_id").AsInt32().NotNullable()
                .WithColumn("clo1").AsString(255).NotNullable().NotNullable();              


                Create.PrimaryKey("pk_" + tableName + "_id").OnTable(tableName).WithSchema(schemaName).Column("id");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here which class include ***[Tags("service")]*** tags run from window service other than run from desktop application.

Please give me solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do it the following way:

- Implement your own service into which you inject your current application's type parameter ("service" or "desktop")
- Then you implement a single method in this service which will get type's Tag attributes' values list as parameter and check if it contains corresponding tag ("service" / "desktop")
- Then you inject this service into your migrations ([as it is shown here in documentation of Fluent Migrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/obsolete/app-context.html)) and call the method you implemented in previous step to check if the migration should be executed